# Delete reciprocal duplicates in Excel

Tags: excel, duplicates

I'm trying to find a quick way to delete reciprocal duplicates between two columns.
For example, `COG00035` is in column A and `COG00065` is in B.
I have to look to make sure that further down there isn't  `A:COG00065` & `B: COG00035`.
I would do this manually but there is literally thousands of rows I would to look for. And the entire row has to be deleted as A and B have to stay together. Thanks!
If you need a better example let me know.

Comment: Would a VBA solution be acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Two-step process:

1) **Remove duplicates in the same order**

Add a third column in C that combines the first two, or:

`=concatenate(A1, B1)`

And drag that all the way down to the end of your data. Then, select your entire data table (from A1 all the way to C# where # is the last row number), go to Data->Remove duplicates, and unselect Columns A and B in the next pop-window (only column C should be selected).

Press "OK" - this should remove any row that has a duplicate in column C, which essentially means columns A and B are the same.

2) **Remove duplicates in reciprocal order**

Add a fourth column that combines the first two in reverse order, or:

`=concatenate(B1, A1)`

In the fifth column, add a formula that counts whether any individual cell in Column C is found in Column D, restricted the area in Column D that is below the row of that individual cell.

For example:

Formula in C1: `=CONCATENATE(A1,B1)`

Formula in D1: `=CONCATENATE(B1,A1)`

Formula in E1: `=COUNTIF(D2:$D$100,C1)`

...assuming your table has 100 cells (e.g., $D$100 is last row). What this will do is show 0s in Column E for rows that are unique, and 1s for rows that are duplicates. You can then filter column E to show the 1s and then delete all the visible cells (Home -> Find & Select -> Go To Special... -> Visible cells only; Ctrl + - to delete rows)

Comment: Based on his question, shouldn't your formula be `=CONCATENATE(B1,A1)` ??

Comment: Her, and no the order shouldn't matter

Comment: Gotcha - edited my answer above. Let me know if that works! Tried on sample file and it seemed to be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **Data > Remove Duplicates**?

You should be able to select what columns you want to include in the comparison. I assume in this case you'd check both the columns you have and if there is duplicate rows matching both entries then they will be removed.

Short overview of this on [the Office website](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2).

Comment: Unfortunately remove duplicates doesn't work. Because they are reciprocal duplicates, excel doesn't pick them up as duplicated. For example, one row is A: COG00035 B: COG00065. But if I find a row that says A: COG00065 B: COG00035, I need it removed, but based on the order Excel does not see that as duplicated. I have used concatenate to combine the two columns and then used a second concatenate formula to flip the columns to show the reciprocals.